# Groovy script doesn't find file in resources

Tags: file, gradle, groovy

I have a small Gradle project I just started that has a single Groovy script in `src/main/groovy` and a text file in `src/main/resources/input/myInput.txt`. My script just has this content currently:

```
def food = [:]
currentFood = 0
currentElf = 0

new File('src/main/resources/input/myInput.txt').eachLine { line ->
    if (line.isBlank()) {
        food[currentElf++] = currentFood
        currentFood = 0
    } else {
        currentFood += line.toInteger()
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/input/myInput.txt`. This is pretty much straight from [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-io), which are usually pretty reliable. What is going wrong here?

Comment: How are you running it?  Are you using a build tool?  What directory does it think you're in when you run it?  `println(new File('.').absolutePath)` should resolve that...  I suspect you're running it from inside the `src/main/groovy` folder...  If so, just stick your AOC input file inside the same folder, and load it with `new File('myInput.txt')`

Comment: Running it using IntelliJ's run configuration. It is indeed using `src/main/groovy` as the working directory. Isn't there a way to reference files in `src/main/resources` from main?

Comment: Can you share your project on GitHub or something?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/spartanhooah/advent-of-code-groovy

Comment: Answer below, and pr sent  have fun with advent of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading it via File, load it via the class and getResourcesAsStream like so:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/input/day-1-small.txt").eachLine { line ->
```